# refactor data service in Vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a Vue project that's underway, the files which are responsible for communicating with the API have been grouped into a "services" section.  While the code shown below works fine as written, it seems like simplifying it would be beneficial due to these factors:

1. there will be several more API specific files needed to support the project
2. the code in the 2 example API specific files shown below is essentially the same except for the value in the `resource` const

**src/services/service.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'advancedplanningextension/api/'
})
```

API specific files -
**src/services/official-scenarios-service.js**

```
import service from './service';

const resource = 'scenariolog';

export default {
    get() {
        return service.get(`${resource}`);
    }
}
```

**src/services/parameters-service.js**

```
import service from './service';

const resource = 'parameter';

export default {
    get() {
        return service.get(`${resource}`);
    }
}
```

file to choose the right API specific file -
**src/services/service-factory.js**

```
import OfficialScenariosService from './official-scenarios-service';
import ParametersService from './parameters-service';

const services = {
    officialScenarios: OfficialScenariosService,
    parameters: ParametersService
    // add more here
}

export const ServiceFactory = {
    get: name => services[name]
}
```

plugin file -
**src/plugins/service.js**

```
import { ServiceFactory } from '../services/service-factory';

export default {
    install: function(Vue) {
        Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$service', { value: ServiceFactory });
    }
}
```

pertinent code in **src/main.js** that shows wiring of plugin file -

```
import ServicePlugin from './plugins/service';
Vue.use(ServicePlugin);
```

Example usage in **src/views/official-scenarios.vue** -

```
<template>
    {{ officialScenarios }}
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
                officialScenarios: []                
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async getOfficialScenarios() {
            const { data } = await this.$service.get('officialScenarios').get();            
            this.officialScenarios = data;
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.getOfficialScenarios(); 
    }
}
</script>
```

I tried creating a **src/services/generic-service.js** file (to replace the 2 API specific files), with the intent of calling that from src/services/service-factory.js, but quickly realized I didn't know how to populate the `resource` when it was called in that manner.
**src/services/generic-service.js** -

```
import service from './service';

let resource = '';  // don't know how to populate this from caller service-factory.js to access the correct API

export default {
    get() {
        return service.get(`${resource}`);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to set the `resource` variable when **service-factory.js** calls the **generic-service.js** file?  Or perhaps there is a way to incorporate the logic from **generic-service.js** directly into **service-factory.js**...?  Or maybe there is a simpler approach than these options...?

**OUTCOME**
Many thanks to @Estus Flask for the answer and follow up information.  For now, I decided to put all the services logic into src/services/index.js.  If the project grows beyond needing more than `createService` I'll deal with refactoring at that point.  Below is the code that seems to be working -
**src/services/index.js** -

```
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'advancedplanningextension/api/'
});

const createService = resource => ({
    get() {
        return axiosInstance.get(`${resource}`);
    }
    // add more here
});

const resources = {
    officialScenarios: 'scenariolog',
    parameters: 'parameter'
    // add more here
}

export const service = {
    get: name => createService(resources[name])
}
```

The values in `resources` are the specific API endpoints.  So when the code calls the service for officialScenarios for example, the URL for that API endpoint will be 'advancedplanningextension/api/scenariolog'.

**src/plugins/service.js** -

```
import { service } from '../services/index';

export default {
    install: function(Vue) {
        Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$service', { value: service });
    }
}
```

Example usage in src/views/official-scenarios.vue remains the same as shown in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved with factory function:

*base-service.js*

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'advancedplanningextension/api/'
});

export const createService = resource => ({
    get() {
        return axiosInstance.get(`${resource}`);
    },
    // etc.
});
```

*foo-service.js*

```
import { createService } from './base-service';

export default createService('foo');
```

`service-factory` name is misleading because it isn't really a factory, just a wrapper module. The same thing can be rewritten more efficiently as [barrel module](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/barrel) (which is commonly index module):

*services/index.js*

```
export { default as foo } from './foo-service';
export { default as bar } from './foo-service';
```

Then it gets all benefits of ES modules such as tree-shaking and can be used as:

```
import * as services from './services';

services.foo.get(...);
```

Comment: Follow up question #1: In base-service.js, should this line `return service.get(\`${resource}\`);` be `return axiosInstance.get(\`${resource}\`);`?

Comment: Follow up question #2: in base-service.js, can more methods be added within `export const createService`?  For instance, this project will require the CRUD operations so could add, update and delete methods be added within `createService`?

Comment: Follow up question #3: The file named foo-service.js, is that considered a factory function or a barrel module?

Comment: Yes, `service` was a typo. Yes, you can add any methods you need to the object that createService creates. foo-service.js is neither of the above, it's just a module. `createService` is what's called factory function, it's a factory for new objects. `index.js` is a barrel.

Comment: Follow up question #4: Is foo-service.js essentially an example of an API specific file?  (In the original post the examples shown were official-scenarios-service.js and parameters-service.js).  If so, does this mean individual modules would still be needed for each API specific file?

Comment: Yes, `foo` stands for `parameters`, etc. I consider this a good way to write it. You can skip all these files, merge base-service and index and write `export const foo = createService('foo'); export const bar = createService('bar')` there but in case services are more than `createService`, it will be hard to maintain it.